# In Windows if I am realtime monitoring a file should I just fflush or _commit as well?

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io

I have a program that writes output to a file and in Notepad++ I am monitoring that file as it is written (in other words when something is written Notepad++ will alert me and ask for permission to reload the file). I am using `fflush` in my program so that when there is output I will be able to see it immediately in Notepad++. I know that Windows also has a `_commit`  command and I want to know if I should call that after the flush.

According to Microsoft [KB66052](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/66052) `fflush` does not write data directly to the disk. It flushes the application buffers but not the OS buffers. Do I need to flush the OS buffers to see my program's output in realtime in Notepad++, or do programs in Windows (like Notepad++) read from the OS buffers?

Thanks

Comment: No, you only need to flush the application buffers (except perhaps if the file is on the network and the two programs are accessing it from different clients).

Comment: @Harry Nobody has submitted an answer to this so if you can explain why only the application buffers need to be flushed (with the exception of network files) please submit it as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks

Comment: Basically the OS keeps only one set of disk buffers, so both applications (since they are running in the same instance of Windows) will always see the same content.  But that's just from my personal knowledge of the way Windows behaves, hopefully someone else can post an answer with appropriate references.